# How to group rows overwriting column value in Big Query SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I wanted to know how to group the rows maintaining the value form one the columns as following:

`tabla_1`

| url | tags | pvs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [www.helloworld.com](http://www.helloworld.com) | bigquery,sql | 200 |
| [www.helloworld.com](http://www.helloworld.com) | - | 100 |
| [www.byeworld.com](http://www.byeworld.com) | python,java | 250 |
| [www.byeworld.com](http://www.byeworld.com) | - | 150 |

and the desired result:

| url | tags | pvs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [www.helloworld.com](http://www.helloworld.com) | bigquery,sql | 300 |
| [www.byeworld.com](http://www.byeworld.com) | python, java | 400 |

I have tried creating two different tables (using filters) and then joining them. I supose there´s a much easier way but I´m not able to find it:

```
SELECT url, tags, sum(pvs)

FROM 
(
   SELECT * FROM tabla_1 WHERE tags != '-'
   LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT * FROM tabla_1 WHERE tags '-')
   ON url
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `-` to `NULL` and get the non-null value with `ARRAY_AGG` function

```
SELECT
  url,
  SUM(pvs) AS total_pvs,
  ARRAY_AGG(IF(tags = '-', NULL, tags) IGNORE NULLS)[OFFSET(0)] AS tags
FROM table_1
GROUP BY url
```